# How can I create a online/offline map in QML?

Tags: qt, plugins, qml, openstreetmap

Currently I have this map. My problem is that the plugin parameter "osm.mapping.offline.directory" loads all tiles in the cache. If I have 20000 tiles in the folder he tries to load all those tiles. This takes a lot of time.

How can I tell the OSM Plugin how many tiles he should load.
If this does not work, have I write a new plugin?

```
Map
{
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    zoomLevel: 14

    property bool isMapOnline = false

    Component.onCompleted: map.plugin = _guiMap.mapIsOnline ? osmPlugin : offlinePlugin

    Plugin
    {
        id: osmPlugin
        name: "osm"
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.host"; value: "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/" }
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.providersrepository.disabled"; value: "true" }
    }

    Plugin
    {
        id: offlinePlugin
        name: "osm"
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.offline.directory"; value: "C:/Tiles" }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at all the parameters that are possible here: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/location-plugin-osm.html - maybe one or a combination of them can archive your goal - just play around with any parameter that has to do anything with caching, storage or memory

Comment: Yes I tried the other parameters but it did not work :/

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution which looks very similar to yours.

First, fix the syntax error in your property initialization.

> property bool isMapOnline: false

Second, replace

> Component.onCompleted: map.plugin = _guiMap.mapIsOnline ? osmPlugin : offlinePlugin

with

> plugin: isMapOnline ? osmPlugin : offlinePlugin

There are some other minor differences; however, this should get you working.